# Como criar link com scroll para página destino

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web

Olá, gostaria de saber como posso fazer um link para minha página de vídeos que role a página para baixo, porém esta página não contém nenhum id para utilizar no modo: `<a href="linkdapagina#localdesejado">`. Tem outra forma? Por exemplo, esse link abre a página e depois faz um scroll de 50% para baixo?

Answer (score 2):

Caso esteja usando `PHP`, pode passar um parâmetro no link, parecido com

**www.seusite.com.br/video1?scroll=true**

Na seção video1 verifique se `GET['scroll'] == 'true'`, caso seja, de um print na seguinte função javascript (ignore o resto)

```js
var metadeDaTela = $(window).height() / 2;

var body = $("html, body");
body.stop().animate({scrollTop:metadeDaTela}, 500, 'swing');
```

```css
body{
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

</body>
```

Na função ele pega a quantidade de pixels da tela e divide por dois, para passar como parâmetro no método `scrollTop`, assim ele irá descer até a metade da página.

Caso queira uma solução somente em `javascript`, terá de apelar para `localStorage` ou até mesmo `SPA´s`.

Answer (score 0):

Com JavaScript puro, você pode fazer deste modo:

**URL da página:**

```
meusite.com.br/#localdesejado
```

ou

```
meusite.com.br/index.html#localdesejado
```

ou

```
meusite.com.br/index.html?localdesejado
```

**Script:**

```
(function(){
    url_ = location.href;
    if(url_.match(/localdesejado/)){
        setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight/2)",1);
    }
})();
```

O script verifica se a string "localdesejado" passado na URL (ex.: `meusite.com.br/#localdesejado`) está presente e faz o `scroll` até a metade da tela.

Usei o parâmetro "**localdesejado**" apenas como exemplo. Você pode usar o termo que quiser no script.

**Por que usei `setTimeout`?**

Porque alguns navegadores (não sei se todos, talvez todos) voltam a tela ao topo automaticamente após o `window.scrollTo`. Usando `setTimeout`, mesmo com um valor mínimo de `1`, esse problema com o navegador é contornado e a tela não volta ao topo.

Answer (score 0):

O melhor jeito de fazer isso é com JavaScript e JQuery com a seguinte função.

Lembre-se de importar o Jquery no head de seu html, se não estiver já adicionado importe ele com:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

**JS:**

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".segundo").offset().top},
        'slow');
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="primeiro"><button type="button">Mostra efeito</button></div>
<div class="segundo">Efeito de Scroll</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.primeiro {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #ccc;
}

.segundo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #999;
}
```

Veja esse exemplo aqui > [Codepen - OnClick Scroll page Javascript & Jquery](https://codepen.io/brunobermejo/pen/ZabaGw)